# Remove inner html tags without inner content Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Remove inner html tags without inner content Javascript. I have html structure like, with undefined div count:

```
 <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>~Content 1~</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I remove all div tags except, the result have to be like:

```
<div>~Content 1~</div>
```

Comment: Did you even try anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vanilla using `document.querySelectorAll`

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");

//just check all divs, if the length of children is 0. there are no more descendants.
Array.prototype.forEach.call(divs, function(element){
if (element.querySelectorAll("div").length == 0)
{
  //only for demo purposes. the element found is the last descendant.
  document.querySelector(".result").textContent += element.outerHTML;
}
});
```

```html
<div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>~Content 1~</div>
        <div>~Content 2~</div>
        <div>~Content 3~</div>        
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<pre class="result"></pre>
```

Comment: sorry can i do that for string not for dom?

Comment: replace `outerHTML` with `textContent`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("div").first().each( function(){ $(this).html( $(this).text() ) });
```

Take first div, and replace its `innerHTML` with its `innerText`

**Demo**

```js
$("div").first().each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).text())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>~Content 1~</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can do inspect element on the content to check that there is only one div remaining.

Answer (score 1):

You can take last child div with `unwrap()`, delete parent divs and then append that div to `body`.

```js
var div = $('div:not(:has(div))').unwrap()
$('div').remove();
$('body').append(div)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>~Content 1~</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```